# Writing Process Dialog log information to text file in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I have created a custom model. When this model is run, it shows a process dialog which has some log information. I want to write that log information into the text file for further analysis.

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Script sample might be very useful here.

Comment: Are you working in Model Builder or arcpy?

Comment: Model Builder @JayGuarneri

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking for. Could you explain what information you expect to be able to obtain from the process dialog and what you hope to do with it? A clear example would be helpful.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to automatically email interim results from model builder?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/15531/753)

Answer (score 5):

That log file information can be enabled and is written out to [History log file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Viewing_tool_execution_history/002100000035000000/).  I would recommend exporting your model as a python script.  You can then open up the .py file in any text editor to execute your text file writing/logging while the script is running.  Alternatively, using python you can read through the history log file and pull out what you want.

Check out this link for reading and writing to text files:

[7.2 Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: In model itself can't I make History log file enabled? @artwork21

Comment: While I am checking in C:\Users\dpurohit\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\log It has some .dat file but it is 0 byte

Comment: Dharmesh, that is not the right folder. Look in the History folder instead.

Comment: Could you pleas point me the right folder?